# Selenium - Python - Why would I use the By class?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I have been searching for the past couple of days to try and figure out the advantage of using the `By` class in Selenium for Python. It seems to return a tuple of strings.

What are the advantages of using this over the standard Selenium way?

Ex: `By.ID, 'password'` vs `find_element_by_id('password')`

In order to do things with Selenium, I need WebElements; so I have no idea on why I would want to use the `By` class. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: I could not find that thread for the life of me. This would technically be a duplicate thread. Thank you SO SO MUCH!

Comment: `find_element_by_*` methods use  `By` under the hood.  They are just a convenience.  There is no advantage to using `By` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main advantage of using By is that it is highly *reusable*.

For example, if you find consistency in the *name* and *type* of submit button of a website like this:

```
<input value="Submit" name="ok" type="submit">
```

You can create a By object and use *driver.findElement* on different page without worrying which method to use, find_element_by_id or find_element_by_xpath:

```
subBtnQuery = By.xpath("//input[@name='ok'][@type='submit']"
driver.get(first_url)
driver.findElement(subBtnQuery)
driver.get(second_url)
driver.findElement(subBtnQuery)
```

In case of html changed, you only need to edit the By object.

#### Further reading

You may also chain the multiple Bys with [ByChained](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/ByChained.html).

#### Extra

As you concern, html ids are often non-unique in the real life scenario. So, most of the time you would like to be very specific of the element to find, that's when *xpath* & *css selector* come handy.

For example, if you try to get google search button from html as below:

```
<input value="Google Search" aria-label="Google Search" name="btnK" type="submit" jsaction="sf.chk">
```

You can make a highly reliable query with xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='btnK'][@type='submit']");
```

or css selector:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='btnK'][type='submit']"))
```

Both of the query are doing the exact same thing which is getting *input* with *name* as 'btnK' and *type* as 'submit'.

Answer (score -1):

ID is when you are looking for a unique/important element. A Class would help you to find the collection of elements. A class can contain many elements, there are chances when you end up with duplicate IDs and Names. Then look for the ClassName first and try to locate the element with ID. This should work as the selenium will look for the ID which is in the mentioned class.

```
    WebElement parentE = driver.findElement(By.className("button"));
    WebElement childE = parentE.findElement(By.id("submit"));
    childE.submit();
```

Comment: If you have duplicate ID's, it's not following good HTML and that needs to be addressed. If I wanted to find a collection of elements, I would do `find_elements_by_class_name`. So still no discernible reason to use the `By` class.